# NIC Teaming having a General Failure Error

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm trying to create a NIC Team for a Windows Server 2012 but I'm getting an error: General Failure.

I tried to restart the server, disconnect all the ethernet cable from the NICs and to deactivate static address for all the NIC but nothing seems to work. I have a second server working perfectly with NIC teaming with 4 NICs and Windows Server 2012 R2.

(The servers are not connected to each other and I'm not using Hyper-V)

Thanks again.
[This is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeByr.png)

Comment: Hardware specs?

Comment: Hi! It's a Windows Server 2012 Dell 620, 32 GB RAM,Xenon E5-2630 , It has four NICs : two Broadcom NetXtreme and two Intel Gigabit 2P I350-t LOM. The Broadcoms NICs are connected using a PCI card. Thanks. I tried to run sfc /scannow but the error is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the nic unplugged and create the team with just 1 NIC plugged into the network.  Make sure that the drivers you have are winHQL drivers.

Comment: Hi! I updated the drivers and discovered that you can create the NIC Team directly from the Device Manager Window. I did that and now the Team is created and working perfectly. From the Server Manager windows never worked. Thanks.